# Yellow leaves in hardy kiwi

Tags: plant-health

I have multiple hardy kiwis on my balcony and one of them started to have strange colour on the leaves, dried out.

[image]
[image]

What could that be from?

My guesses:

- There was a really heavy sun for the recent 4-5 days and I was out for this period so I didn't watered the plant. I started to water them back right after coming back but still, after a week, the problem remains. Maybe my balcony is simply a wrong place for those plants? I'm not sure because, interestingly, this does not happens to 3 other hardy kiwis I have on my balcony, so maybe this particular one is particularly vulnerable.
- I have used running water that may contain too much chlorine or calcium. I've read that for hardy kiwi sometimes leaves begin to yellow because of excess of calcium or iron deficiency. I started to water with iron chelate and the water I use remains in a bottle for two days before using for watering. I've been doing this for a week but I'm not sure if this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: this looks like spider mite damage due to the presence of round pale areas where they have been feeding

Answer (score 4):

Well they do suffer heat stress, so you might be right about that, but I notice a mottled appearance to the leaves, apart from the blackening in the top picture - check the plant for red spider mite infestation, because that's what the mottling reminds me of. A heavy infestation would cause serious stress and damage to the plant, coupled with heat, so if your weather's been hot and dry, it might well be spider mite.